# GL_REPEAT vs a High Resolution Image?

Tags: performance, opengl, graphics, gpu

If I've got a low-resolution texture with a bunch of dots in it which if I did `GL_REPEAT`
It'd be unnoticeable. then Is it advisable to use `GL_REPEAT` by specifying higher texture coordinates to repeat this texture or just use a high-resolution one with all dots I need? (**GPU Performance**)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always get better performance with a smaller texture. If the texture repeats itself and there are no architectural reasons to make it bigger, use the smaller version. Sampling a smaller texture accesses less memory so it is more likely that most (or all) accesses will fall in the GPU's texture cache.